# Charset errors Rsyncing between Debian and Windows 2003 Server (cygwin)

Tags: cygwin, rsync

I've been using `rsync` for a while for incremental rotating backups. The script runs from a Debian to a Windows 2003 server with Cygwin installed (version 2.2.1).

```
rsync -rlptDvih --partial --fake-super --delete --delete-excluded --exclude-from="$EXCLUDES_C" -e "ssh -p $PORT" $USR_ADDR@$BKUP_ADDR:$unit1/$SNAPSHOT_RW/$NAME_FOLDER/$PERIODICITY.0
```

When rsyncing files with some characters (like Ó, é,...) the charset conversion is not fine:

> f.st...... g/Calidad/OLD/T#303#251cnicos/Acuerdo T#303#251cnico de Aseguramiento de Calidad 2016.doc
>
> f.st...... g/Calidad/OLD/Analisis de riesgos/GESTI#303#223N DE RIESGOS COMPANYDICIEMBRE 2015 (WC).docx

I've already tried almost everything and can't figure out how to fix it. Seems that `--iconv` `rsync` parameter should be able to handle this, but I read that the additional "layer" introduced by Cygwin can make this useless. I've tried with `--iconv` and some charset (utf8 and ISO88591) but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try [native openssh port for win32](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH). It might solve the problems introduced by the cygwin layer.

Comment: That didn't work. But I could make it work finally by using this iconv parameter:

--iconv=utf-8,cp1250

cp1250 seems to be the correct charset for Windows 2003 in my case.